# How to let one function wait for another to finish before continuing

Tags: python, kivy

I'm reaching out to you, community, as I've exhausted all ideas on how to make this work.

Basically in one method what I'm doing is that I'm checking a passport with a camera and extracting certain features.

I need the method `send_data_to_the_server()` to wait until the first function `check_passport()` gives me result I'm expecting.
When the result is captured and is `True`, next function (which connects to a server) can carry on.

I've tried to make it work with `time.sleep()` which I found very ineffective as it freezes the whole program and becomes unresponsive and I have to kill it.

Then I tried to use `queue.Queue` with `threading` modules. That freezes too.

my code:

```
def check_passport(self, id, q):  # <-- this function needs to finish and return True
        self.validate_passport = NewUserValidationCamera()
        self.root.add_widget(self.validate_passport)
        if self.validate_passport._passport_passed:  # this private variable will become True at some point
            q.put((id, 'finished'))
        # while not self.validate_passport._passport_passed:
        #     time.sleep(0.5)
        # return True

def send_data_to_the_server(self):  # this method waits until method "check_passport" returns True
    ...
    ...

def register_or_login(self):
        if self.login_screen is False:
            passport_passed = False
            
            q = queue.Queue()
            thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.check_passport, args=(1, q))
            thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.send_data_to_the_server)
            for thread in [thread1, thread2]:
                thread.daemon = True
                thread.start()
            result = q.get()
            print(result)
```

Like I said my solution whether I'm using `time` or `threading` freezes the application. I've also used `while not self.validate_passport._passport_passed: time.sleep(0.5)` but app becomes unresponsive as well.

What you probably also need to know is that `self.validate_passport = NewUserValidationCamera()`
kicks off the whole validation process because it is triggered in the `__init__()` method.

**Updated code to reflect added queue for the second method:**

```
def register_or_login(self):
        if self.login_screen is False:
            passport_passed = False
            
            q1 = queue.Queue()
            q2 = queue.Queue()
            thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.create_a_validation_widget_and_check_passport, args=(1, q1))
            thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.send_data_to_the_server, args=(2, q2))
            for thread in [thread1, thread2]:
                thread.daemon = True
                thread.start()
                thread.join()
            result1 = q1.get()
            result2 = q2.get()
            print(result1)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried thread.join()?

Comment: No, I haven't. Will try ..

Comment: I am not sure of the entire architecture of the app but sounds like you need a file flag on the system, if said file exists, show can go on

Comment: you should use a different queue for `send_data_to_the_server`. have `check_passport` post info on new queue when its done

Comment: @SeyiDaniel  `thread.join()` freezes too.

Comment: Seems like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is in order here, so others can reproduce your problem. - sometimes the process of paring something down to a minimal thing that still exhibits the problem will lead you to figure it out yourself.  If it doesn't do that, it might help you at least narrow down the problem for yourself.

Comment: @Steve  Minimal example code is relative easy in this case. All you need is 2 functions and threading. Have `random.randint()` to keep giving you random numbers. If the first function returns even number and greater than 100 the second function can kick off.

Comment: Why do you need them in separate threads? If you must have them in separate threads it would make sense to either have a queue with a separate long running job or thread signaling.

Comment: @niclaslindgren  I admit this is the first time I'm actually using threading in the real project. I don't mind using just one thread as long as the second method waits for `True` from the first method.

Comment: Ok maybe I'm misunderstanding here. But can't the password method just invoke the send data method when it's ready?

Comment: @Mark, if "Minimal example code is relative easy", then you should supply it in your question to have the best chance of getting the answer you seek.

Comment: I haven't yet grasped what the crux of the question is here.  I don't think it has anything to do with the thread code.  That all seems straightforward and right.  `create_a_validation_widget_and_check_passport1` should run, and if it returns normally, `send_data_to_the_server` should then run.  I just stripped your code down to two simple functions, and it worked both to just use `join()` the way you're doing here, and also to set both threads off at once and have one wait for a global variable to be changed by the other before it does its business.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Queue and thread.join together like that

```
def __init__(self):
    self.que = queue.Queue() # will use for get the data from the check_passport
    self.thread1 = None #  will use this attribute in send_data method to wait the check_passport
    self.register_or_login()

def check_passport(self, id, q):
    self.validate_passport = NewUserValidationCamera()
    self.root.add_widget(self.validate_passport)
    if self.validate_passport._passport_passed:  
        q.put((id, 'finished'))
    return True

def send_data_to_the_server(self):  
    self.thread1.join() # The method waits for the thread1
    print("check_passport: ", self.que.get())
...

def register_or_login(self):
    if self.login_screen is False:
        passport_passed = False
        
        self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=lamda id, q: self.que.put(self.check_passport(id, q)), args=(1, q)) 
        # the lambda function puts the result of the check_passport in the self.que
        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.send_data_to_the_server)
        for thread in [self.thread1, thread2]:
            thread.daemon = True
            thread.start()
        result = q.get() 
        print(result)
```

Edit:
Before I answered the question, I wrote small example and I would like to share the example so you can test the code.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.que = queue.Queue()
        self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda arg1, arg2: self.que.put(self.func_1(arg1, arg2)), args=["hello", "world"])
        self.thread1.start()
        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.func_2)
        thread2.start()
    
    def func_1(self, foo_1, foo_2):
        for bar in range(10):
            print(bar)
            time.sleep(1)
    
        return "{} {}".format(foo_1, foo_2)

    def func_2(self):
        self.thread1.join()
        result = self.que.get()
        print(result)
```

Comment: Did you actually run this code and see that it works?  I'm not being at a critical, and I don't know if it should or shouldn't work.  That's why I'm asking.  I'm just curious.

Comment: Not this code but I wrote small example. I don't know how to add my small example code in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did at the end was following what @niclaslindgren suggested in his own way. I call it "KISS" approach or also known as "Keep It Simple Stupid". I also took on board what @Steve said about using global variables. I'm not a big fan of global variables but they do have its own place in programming.
The below did the trick for me:

```
PASSPORT_VALIDATED = False

class NewUserValidationCamera(Image):

    ...
    ...
    def update(self, dt):
        ...
        ...
        if self.names[label] == 'ma' and self._passport_keyword_passed and self._gender_check_passed:
            global PASSPORT_VALIDATED
            PASSPORT_VALIDATED = True

class MainApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_for_True, 1.0)
        ...
        ...

    def check_for_True(self, dt):
        if PASSPORT_VALIDATED:
            Clock.unschedule(self.check_for_True)
            self.send_data_to_the_server()

    def send_data_to_the_server(self):  
        ...
        ...

    def register_or_login(self):
        if self.login_screen is False:
            passport_passed = False
        
            self.validate_passport = NewUserValidationCamera()
            self.root.add_widget(self.validate_passport)
```